# Why are fields named differently on the child relationship entity vs the actual child object?

Tags: soql, schema

`ProcessInstance` has a child relationship with `ProcessInstanceHistory`.  This relationship is called `StepsAndWorkitems`.  Here it is in Eclipse's Schema Browser.

[image]

Now, let's examine the actual child object (`ProcessInstanceHistory`) and compare it to the one in the child relationship.

[image]

Note that in the Child Relationship, field `ProcessInstanceHistory.StepStatus` is marked as `Status`.

Why is this, why are fields named differently?  Where are these names in the child relationship defined?  Is this just an inconsistency?

Comment: I'd guess it's due to a poor design decision early on and Salesforce didn't want to fix it later since it would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MikeChale noted, this is probably just because of something Salesforce implemented early on. I haven't been able to find anything concrete that specifies why the child relationship names are different.

Comment: They did it for clarity. For example, look at any activity-enabled object, and you'll see two children: ActivityHistories and OpenActivities. There's not even an *object* that goes by this name (it combines tasks and events), but it exists. Salesforce tends to have many "magic" features that exist solely as a "convenience" to the developers; apparently they haven't learned that constant exceptions make a developer's work harder.